# No such file or directory -../ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/C/gems/sass-3.2.12/VERSION

Tags: java, jboss, liferay-6

I get this error

```
`22:29:23,521 INFO  
22:29:46,030 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2) Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - classpath:C:/servers/as-server/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final-6.2.0-m6/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/C/gems/sass-3.2.12/VERSION
22:29:46,033 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)   initialize at org/jruby/RubyFile.java:442
22:29:46,034 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)         open at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1111
22:29:46,035 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)         open at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:298
22:29:46,036 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)         read at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:3343
22:29:46,036 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)      version at classpath:/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/version.rb:53
22:29:46,037 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)         Sass at classpath:/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/version.rb:125
22:29:46,037 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)       (root) at classpath:/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/version.rb:8
22:29:46,038 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)      require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
22:29:46,039 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)       (root) at classpath:/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass/version.rb:9
22:29:46,039 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)      require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
22:29:46,040 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)       (root) at classpath:/gems/sass-3.2.12/lib/sass.rb:2
22:29:46,040 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)      require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
22:29:46,041 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)       (root) at classpath:/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/dependencies.rb:5
22:29:46,041 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)         each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612
22:29:46,042 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)       (root) at classpath:/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4
22:29:46,042 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)      require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
22:29:46,042 ERROR [stderr] (com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor-2)       (root) at classpath:/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:1
22:29:46,045 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6) 22:29:46,043 ERROR [http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6][AggregateFilter:459] Unable to parse SASS on CSS /css/profile/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css
22:29:46,047 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6) com.liferay.portal.kernel.scripting.ScriptingException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (Errno::ENOENT) classpath:C:/servers/as-server/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final-6.2.0-m6/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/C/gems/sass-3.2.12/VERSION
22:29:46,048 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor.eval(RubyExecutor.java:254)
22:29:46,049 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor.eval(RubyExecutor.java:129)
22:29:46,049 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.dynamiccss.DynamicCSSUtil._parseSass(DynamicCSSUtil.java:509)
22:29:46,051 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.dynamiccss.DynamicCSSUtil.parseSass(DynamicCSSUtil.java:178)
22:29:46,052 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.aggregate.AggregateFilter.getCssContent(AggregateFilter.java:455)
22:29:46,052 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.aggregate.AggregateFilter.getCssContent(AggregateFilter.java:494)
22:29:46,053 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.aggregate.AggregateFilter.getContent(AggregateFilter.java:395)
22:29:46,054 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.aggregate.AggregateFilter.processFilter(AggregateFilter.java:511)
22:29:46,055 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
22:29:46,056 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
22:29:46,057 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
22:29:46,058 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
22:29:46,058 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
22:29:46,059 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
22:29:46,060 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor639.invoke(Unknown Source)
22:29:46,061 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
22:29:46,061 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
22:29:46,062 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
22:29:46,063 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy872.doFilter(Unknown Source)
22:29:46,064 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
22:29:46,064 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
22:29:46,065 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
22:29:46,066 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
22:29:46,067 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
22:29:46,067 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
22:29:46,068 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
22:29:46,068 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
22:29:46,069 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
22:29:46,070 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor639.invoke(Unknown Source)
22:29:46,071 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
22:29:46,073 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
22:29:46,074 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
22:29:46,074 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy872.doFilter(Unknown Source)
22:29:46,075 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
22:29:46,076 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
22:29:46,077 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter.processFilter(CacheFilter.java:421)
22:29:46,078 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
22:29:46,079 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
22:29:46,080 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
22:29:46,080 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
22:29:46,081 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
22:29:46,082 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
22:29:46,082 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor639.invoke(Unknown Source)
22:29:46,083 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
22:29:46,084 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
22:29:46,085 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
22:29:46,086 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy872.doFilter(Unknown Source)
22:29:46,086 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
22:29:46,087 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
22:29:46,088 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:86)
22:29:46,090 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
22:29:46,091 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
22:29:46,091 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
22:29:46,092 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
22:29:46,093 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
22:29:46,093 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
22:29:46,094 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor639.invoke(Unknown Source)
22:29:46,094 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
22:29:46,095 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
22:29:46,096 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
22:29:46,096 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy872.doFilter(Unknown Source)
22:29:46,097 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
22:29:46,098 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
22:29:46,098 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.header.HeaderFilter.processFilter(HeaderFilter.java:154)
22:29:46,099 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
22:29:46,099 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
22:29:46,100 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
22:29:46,101 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
22:29:46,103 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
22:29:46,104 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
22:29:46,106 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor639.invoke(Unknown Source)
22:29:46,107 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
22:29:46,107 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
22:29:46,108 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
22:29:46,109 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy872.doFilter(Unknown Source)
22:29:46,109 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
22:29:46,110 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
22:29:46,111 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
22:29:46,111 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
22:29:46,112 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
22:29:46,113 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
22:29:46,114 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:119)
22:29:46,115 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
22:29:46,116 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
22:29:46,117 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
22:29:46,117 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
22:29:46,118 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
22:29:46,118 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:389)
22:29:46,119 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
22:29:46,119 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
22:29:46,120 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
22:29:46,121 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
22:29:46,121 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
22:29:46,122 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
22:29:46,122 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
22:29:46,124 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
22:29:46,124 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
22:29:46,125 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
22:29:46,126 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
22:29:46,126 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (Errno::ENOENT) classpath:C:/servers/as-server/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final-6.2.0-m6/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/C/gems/sass-3.2.12/VERSION
22:29:46,127 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
22:29:46,128 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
22:29:46,128 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor.eval(RubyExecutor.java:248)
22:29:46,129 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        ... 98 more
22:29:46,130 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6) Caused by: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (Errno::ENOENT) classpath:C:/servers/as-server/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final-6.2.0-m6/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/C/gems/sass-3.2.12/VERSION
22:29:46,130 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:127)
22:29:46,131 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1231)
22:29:46,132 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1224)
22:29:46,133 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor.doEval(RubyExecutor.java:189)
22:29:46,135 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor$EvalCallable.call(RubyExecutor.java:332)
22:29:46,136 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ruby.RubyExecutor$EvalCallable.call(RubyExecutor.java:1)
22:29:46,137 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
22:29:46,138 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6)        ... 1 more
22:29:46,139 INFO  [stdout] (http-activate.navicat.com/127.0.0.1:8080-6) Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (Errno::ENOENT) classpath:C:/servers/as-server/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final-6.2.0-m6/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/C/gems/sass-3.2.12/VERSION`
```

What can be the problem?

I removed this dependency `cxf-rt-ws-policy`, but I don't think that is the problem.

The program runs on *Java 7 Liferay* and *Jboss*. Maybe it is liferay problem.

I don't find this path:

> C:/servers/as-server/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final-6.2.0-m6/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/C/gems/sass-3.2.12/VERSION

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your classpath is messed up. As you don't give more information about steps to reproduce or your system, I can only guess that the path that you describe should correctly be named

C:/servers/as-server/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final-6.2.0-m6/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/;C:/gems/sass-3.2.12/VERSION

however, what the VERSION in there does is beyond me.

Check all your classpath configuration for jboss, e.g. (if I remember correctly) settings in module(s?).xml and other files that you have edited.

I also hope that the `6.2.0-m6` in your path doesn't refer to a prerelease milestone of the already outdated Liferay version 6.2 - at a minimum you should be using a GA version, and ideally the latest or, even better, the latest major release. If I'm not mistaken, the latest release doesn't use Ruby parsing any more, so that *this* problem definitely would go away (at the price of a major upgrade, yes, I know)